# Mac Websharing Off but Process Running

Tags: mac

I have my mac setup to use php / mysql / apache via macports. Recently it has gone a bit pear shaped: it seems that the local mac versions of apache and mysql are running blocking the macports services:

```
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
```

Web sharing in System preferences is off - How can I properly disable it? I tried turning it on an off again in System Preferences but it would not changed from off to on.

Also if I kill the process it starts running again.

Comment: Where then should I ask this question? I didn't think it was appropriate for stackoverflow and it does relate to running an apache server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's the builtin Mac versions, or if it is they're being activated in an unusual way. From the fact that it restarts when killed, I'd infer that it's being started and monitored by launchd, but you need to figure out which launchd item is managing it, and unload that item. To do this, run `sudo launchctl list`, search for the PID of the running process, then find the launchd item (in /Library/LaunchDaemons or /System/Library/LaunchDaemons) with the matching label, and unload it with `sudo launchctl unload -w /path/to/item'.  See [this previous answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/285078/how-can-i-prevent-a-process-from-running-under-mac-osx-10-6/285088#285088) for more details.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you! I now have my macports version of apache running again. Now the problem is that I still have the mac version of mysql running - in phpmyadmin I see only old tables I had in there. Nothing that was on the macports version. I can't find the launcher for this in either of the directories mentioned - launch item that seems to start the process is 0x109a2a500.anonymous.mysqld